# how to get image digest(sha) via opa policy

Tags: open-policy-agent

I want to create policy that will check that image digest (sha) is part of white list and will approve it.

My problem is that the deployment done via image name and image tag and I try to find a way to convert the tag to sha on the fly.

Does OPA can do get sha of image?

Answer (score 0):

A Docker image's digest is the SHA256 of its `config.json` file. Without this (i.e. from only the repository and tag) you can't create the digest, with OPA or any other tool. If you *do* have the `config.json` file at hand you can create the digest using it as input to the `crypto.sha256(string)` [built-in](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#cryptography), but you are probably better off retrieving the digest directly from either the Docker API or you registry, depending on your use case.